# PayPal MECL for Android: "This transaction has expired ..."

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I’m using the mobile express checkout library for android and get always the following message when testing the checkout in sandbox mode:

"This transaction has expired. Please return to the recipient's website to complete your transaction using their regular checkout flow."

my steps:

1. using the default sandbox API key: APP-80W284485P519543T
2. fetch the device reference token with the API key in PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX mode
3. place the PayPal button
4. using the API credentials from my PayPal developer account
5. send the "SetExpressCheckout" request and get the PayPal token
6. show the checkout site in a WebView with the following URL:

String URL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout-mobile&drt=" +
    DeviceReferenceToken + "&token=" + PayPalToken + "&useraction=commit";

The confusing thing is that all seems to work using the live URL (https://www.paypal.com/webscr) where I can see the PayPal login instead of the error message (still using the sandbox API key and the sandbox mode). But before going live I want to test it with the sandbox accounts of course.

Do I forgot something important or is it maybe because of the recent changes in the PayPal sandbox?

Thanks in advance!